# Find the missing element?

Tags: mathematics, sequence

I've been trying to solve this for quite some time, can you help me solve it?
This puzzle was made by one of my friend's teachers. This is not copyrighted and cannot be found anywhere on the internet.

Hint: A mathematical operator is used (+,-,X,/)
[image]

Comment: "This puzzle was made by one of my friend's teachers. This is not copyrighted and cannot be found anywhere on the internet." My understanding is that, if they created this image, or wrote it down anywhere else, it is automatically copyrighted.